# Host Header Attack on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, http-headers

i got this issue from IT-Sec, i have read and search thouroghly but i still can't find any actual solution to fix this issue. Here it is.

> "HTTP Host header can be controlled by an attacker. This can be exploited using web-cache poisoning and by abusing alternative channels.  Pentester try to request with modify header host. and the response result showing with the modify host header. affected files:
>
> > 1. app/formulir
> > 2. app/kompensasi
> > 3. app/panduan-agen
> > 4. app/produk-dan-layanan
> > 5. app/tentang
> > 6. app/tentang-
> > 7. app/training
>
> The impact of this vulnerability
>   An attacker can manipulate the Host header as seen by the web application and cause the application to behave in unexpected ways."

This is the header sc :
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyzZW.png)

Recommended solution thus far is :

> The web application should use the SERVER_NAME instead of the Host header

This app are running on xampp with reverse proxy setting for testing. I already do 3 changes to config.php, but the issue is still there. Here is the code.

```
if(isset($_SERVER[SERVER_NAME])) { 
$config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&  strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$config['base_url'] = '://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$config['base_url'] = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
}
else{
$config['base_url'] = '';
}
```

and 2 :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]';
```

and 3 :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://jktdc.*********.com/app'
```

**What im asking is, how/where/what exactly i have to change/add to fix this issue. Not a bashing. Thanks a lot.**

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
$url = ''
$config[base_url] = $url
```

so it will accept whatever the servername is.